# preg_match and my string

Tags: php, preg-match

I would like to have this kind of string:

**basically a string of just letters a-zA-Z that can (or cannot) end with à or è or ì or ù.**

I did this:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+$|^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/', $word)
```

and I still think is alright but for some reason it doesn't do the job!

EDIT:
There are some italian lastname that can end with àèìòù but some other ones just end with a letter. I want to get that the end of the string can end either with àèìòù or with a letter.

this is the full code

```
if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/', $word) ) {
    echo "0";

} else {
    echo LASTNAME_ERROR;
}
```

but when I execute it, it gaves me the LASTNAME_ERROR

Comment: can or cannot? So you're saying either a string with any upper case or lower case letters in it, and potentially ending in the symbols or not?

Comment: I think this pattern is enough `^([a-zA-Z])+([àèìòù])?$`

Comment: Which character encoding is used in `$word` and which character encoding is used for the PHP script? (See as well my edit in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383649/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description I would formulate the regular expression as followed:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/
```

however from your question it is not clear where exactly your problem is. Your regex looks a bit verbose but not that faulty that it would explain your problem (at least not to me).

***Edit:*** After re-reading your question I see one thing: The variable `$word` might contain UTF-8 encoded data. If that is the case you need to add the [*`u` (PCRE_UTF8)* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) to the regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/u
                     ^
                     `--- UTF-8 modifier
```

This is also true the other way round: If you don't use UTF-8 yet for your application but the PHP files are encoded in UTF-8 the regular expression above is not valid, too.

So check the character encoding of both the string and your PHP file, that is one thing I could assume what can go wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's just review some of your Regex, so you can see where you went wrong.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]
```

So one or more a-zA-Z's, followed by an a-zA-Z. Well that's really rather pointless:
`/^[a-zA-Z]+` would suffice.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/
```

So a-zA-Z one or more times, followed by one or more of your symbols. Well, that's awfully similar to your original regular expression, so let's cut away and put it back together.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[àèìòù]?$/
```

So we've got a-zA-Z one or more times, followed by the symbols, 0 or more times at the end of the string. **Just to note, Hakre devised this answer first. I just wanted to explain some of your mistakes.**

Answer (score 0):

This should be work

```
/((?!\(à|è|ì|ò|ù)$)[a-zA-Z])+/

(            # start a group for the purposes of repeating
 (à|è|ì|ò|ù) # negative lookahead assertion for the pattern à|è|ì|ò|ù
 [a-zA-Z]    # your own pattern for matching a URL character
)+           # repeat the group
```